# Trying to deploy HEDA package in a scratch org

Tags: salesforcedx, package

I'm trying to add fields to an object (hed__Affiliation__c) in the HEDA package.
But when I install the package in my scratch org  with the "sfdx force:package:install" command I can't see that object...

I had also tried another way: I have "Refreshed from server" my PRO org with Eclipse and the Force.com plugin and can't see it!

Of course it is there: I can reach it with the developer console, with "hed" namespace...

There is an Affiliation.object file but there aren't the fields I can see with the developer console....

So... where are the custom objects? How can I get it? Where I am wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: It sounds like you don't have FLS/CRUD permissions to the packaged objects. Does it come with a Permission Set you can assign to your scratch org user?

Comment: I can't see any special perm... Since it is a managed package, maybe is somehow protected??